# Show $\mathbb{S}^{2}/\mathbb{S}^{0}$ is homotopy equivalent to $\mathbb{S}^{2} \vee \mathbb{S}^{1}$.

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Let $X=\mathbb{S}^{2}/\mathbb{S}^{0}$ be the space resulting from collapsing one pair of antipodal points on a two-dimensional sphere to a single point.  Let $Y$ be $\mathbb{S}^{2} \vee \mathbb{S}^{1}$. Specifically, $Y$ fits in the following pushout diagram. 
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
\ \{a\} @>{f}>> \mathbb{S}^{2}\\
@VgVV @VVV\\
\ \mathbb{S}^{1} @>>> Y
\end{CD}

Where $\{a\}$ is a one-point space with $f(a)=(1,0,0)$ and $g(a)=(1,0)$.

Are $X$ and $Y$ homotopy equivalent?  If they are, how can I see it?  Can it be solved using the fact that a space $X$ has the homotopy extension property with respect to a subspace $A$ if and only if $([0,1]\times A) \cup(\{0\}\times X)$ is a retract of $[0,1]\times X$?

Comment: This is not a formal answer, but think, as an "intermediate step", of the sphere $S^2$ where two near points $x$ and $y$ are joined with an arc $c$ that only intersects the sphere in $x$ and $y$.

Comment: It occured that my answer is wrong. https://www.math3ma.com/blog/clever-homotopy-equivalences?fbclid=IwAR07TYypWvcoz262XQQr2nO3-uG13OU9mO5jhzsQTA6qjfXbYJChxG7EJ88

Comment: Related to https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3040181.