# homotopy equivalence of these three spaces

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

[image]

$S^2$ with a diameter

$T^2$ with a disk

$S^2$ with a circle

i try to find a space such that they are all the deformation contraction of it. And i failed.

any idea is helpful. thanks

Comment: In $(a)$, contract the diameter and squeeze out a disc around the double point to go $(a)\Rightarrow (b)$. Also in $(a)$, take one end of the diameter and drag it continuously around the surface of $S^2$ till it coincides with the point at the other end. This gives you $(c)$ with the $S^1$ inside the $S^2$, and this is completely fine.

Comment: Similar to https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3023209.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to show that all three spaces $S_1, S_2, S_3$ are homotopy equivalent. To do this, it is not necessary to find a space $S$ such that each $S_i$ is a deformation  retract (but I shall come back to this point later).

I shall use the following two well-known theorems:

If $A \hookrightarrow X$ is a cofibration and $A$ is contractible, then the qotient map $X \to X/A$ is a homotopy equivalence.

If $X$ is a CW-complex and $A$ is a subcomplex, then $A \hookrightarrow X$ is a cofibration.

Appyling these theorems to $(S_1,diameter)$ and $(S_2,disk)$, we see that both spaces are homotopy equivalent to $S^2/S^0$, where $S^0$ is regarded as the set consisting of north and south pole. That this space is homotopy equivalent to $S_3$ has been shown in [Show $\mathbb{S}^{2}/\mathbb{S}^{0}$ is homotopy equivalent to $\mathbb{S}^{2} \vee \mathbb{S}^{1}$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3023209). See [the link](https://www.math3ma.com/blog/clever-homotopy-equivalences?fbclid=IwAR07TYypWvcoz262XQQr2nO3-uG13OU9mO5jhzsQTA6qjfXbYJChxG7EJ88) in Igor Sikora's comment.

To find a space $S$ such that all $S_i$ are deformation retracts of $S$, you can proceed as follows:

Let $f : X \to Y$ be a map. Then $Y$ embeds as the base of the mapping cylinder $C(f)$ of $f$ which is a strong deformation retract of $C(f)$. Moreover, $X$ embeds as the top of $C(f)$. It is a well-known that $f$ is a homotopy equivalence if and only if $X$ is a deformation retract of $C(f)$.

Hence any two homotopy equivalent spaces embed as deformation retracts into a bigger space. You can iterate this to finitey many homotopy equivalent spaces.