# Homeomorphism from punctured sphere to horn torus

Tags: general-topology, compactness, compactification

Im working on a problem about 1 point compactification, and i am at a step where I want to take the punctured sphere $$ S^{2}\setminus\left\{ (0,0,1)\right\}= \left \{ (x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3 \, \mid \, x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 1 \right\} \setminus\left\{ (0,0,1)\right\} $$

and identify the poles with one another to get the horn torus of radius 1/2 with no centre, parameterized by the following equations (wikipedia for reference):
$$ (x,y,z) = \frac{1}{2} \left( (1+\cos\theta ) \cos\varphi, (1+\cos\theta ) \sin\varphi, \sin\theta \right) $$

The question does not require me to state the homeomorphism explicity, but I have been trying for too long and at this point need to know for the sake of interest...

I have tried various ways of mapping spherical coordinates into this torus, but i think that is the wrong approach since it seems to always have a dead end

Comment: You should explain what the first space is. You remove the north pole and then identify the poles? Probably you remove both poles.

Comment: Similar: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3040181.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Map that sends points from the torus to the sphere st. point is sent to it's projection through the origin works (cf. attached picture)

[image]

Comment: Ok thank you, at least there is a clear map instead of "identify the poles with one another"